# Django Rest Framework Bulk Update

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have been dealing with this problem a while now and cannot seem to fix it, there are three steps that I am doing this

1: First I am uploading images via an AJAX POST
2: I am inserting a campaign
3: I want to update the images table with the foreign key of ads

this means when a serializer.save() is being called with success, to make a bulk update in the images table with the ads.id

here it is my code:

```
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    #data = json.dumps(request.data)
    user = self.request.user
    if user.groups.filter(name='advertisers').exists():
        serializer = CampaignSerializer(data=request.data)

        AdsId = AdsImages.objects.filter(id__in=self.request.data["adsImages"][0]["image"])

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save(advertiser=self.request.user)
            ad_id = serializer.data['ads'][0]['id']

            for ad in AdsId:
                AdsImagesSerializer(AdsImages,data=ad_id, partial=True)

            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED,)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    else:
        return Response({
                            'status':'Unauthorized',
                            'message':'This account is not authorized to do this request'
                    }, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
    return super(CampaignStart, self).perform_create(serializer)
```

> AdsId = AdsImages.objects.filter(id__in=self.request.data["adsImages"][0]["image"])

this get's the images ID's that were previously uploaded, it's a DICTIONARY

```
for ad in AdsId:
       AdsImagesSerializer(AdsImages,data=ad_id, partial=True)
```

here I am trying to make a foreach Image["ID"] update the column of ads with ad_id

and it's not working, I need some help in here

Comment: And, why would you need a serializer for updating models ?

Comment: @Linovia I need that when the Response.Succes comes to update the ads column in the Images with ads.foreignKey